# Write a function which squares a number and then use it to write a function which takes three integers and returns the sum of their squares

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook

Im new to python and cant figure out how to get these functions to call themselves. It asks for an input but no matter what gives 0 as the output. Can someone help debug?

```
userinput = input("Enter three numbers: ")
userinput = userinput.split(',')
finalsum = 0
finaldata = []

def formatinput(x):
 sqrdata = []
  for element in x:    
    sqrdata.append(int(element))
  return(sqrdata)

def findsquare(x):
 return (x*x) 

def sumthesquares(y):
  for element in y:
    temp = findsquare(element)
    finaldata.append(int(temp))
    finalsum = finalsum + temp
  return finalsum

def findthesquares(userinput):
  finalsum = sumthesquares(formatinput(userinput))

print(finalsum)
```

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope in Python. Assigning to variables inside the functions doesn't affect the variables outside the function, unless you use the `global` statement.

Comment: But it would be better if you learned how to return values instead of using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried running your code? From what you've posted, it looks like you never actually call your functions...

They're defined, but you're missing the actual calls, like `formatinput(userinput)`.

For future reference, if you put something like `print("Got here!")` into your functions, you can test that they're being called.

Comment: There are more problems than this, such as variable scope.